# Opening files in the terminal

Tags: terminal

When I try typing

```
texmaker myfile.tex
```

on the command line, I get the following message:

```
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
```

I have no idea what this means.

I'm using Centos

Answer (score 0):

Texmaker is a GUI application, and meant to be used as such. So you can instead just start Texmaker then open the .tex file you want from within the application. This can be accomplished by the Ctrl+O key combination.